# chart serverside export

Tags: charts, server-side, fusioncharts

I am searching for a good graphing utility that can export graphs 100% server side. In other words it takes in the data and returns an image file.

We have used swift charts in the past but our business people have seen fusion charts and Zing charts and want something that looks like that.

Both Zing and Fusion charts have "server side" export where it takes a screen shot in the bowser and sends it to the server when the user clicks a button. This feature also has some limitations from flash which make it more complicated. The graph must be the top image on the page, the window(and tab) must be open and in focus. The graph also must have been viewed in the browser before it can be exported.

If anyone knows of a tool similar to the swift generator or has any figured out how to export fusion charts without a user?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FusionCharts Team has developed a .NET assembly which will enable you to export chart at server without loading the chart in the browser.

You can have it by writing to FusionCharts Support at http://www.fusioncharts.com/contact/ .

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be a little late but there is another way to render and export on the server  (required: PHP 5.2+): [fcimg.org](http://fcimg.org)

"FCImg is a third party tool to allow servers running the LAMP stack to export FusionCharts Charts as images without a need for a browser."

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts are a good candidate. They are very rich in features. There is a java utility - [highcharts-serverside-export](https://github.com/one2team/highcharts-serverside-export) which can be used to export images in png and jpeg format.
I use the above combination btw.

One of the images that I have generated :
[image]